# Nasm - move value from a 4 byte register into an 1 byte address space

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

How does nasm behave when I move the 4 byte value stored in eax, ebx, ecx etc. to an address space that has less than 4 bytes of space allocated? Respectively how does nasm behave when I move a 1 byte value stored in `var` to an 4 byte register?

Like:

```
.bss
var resb 1
.text
mov eax, 2000000000
mov [var], eax

xor ebx, ebx
mov ebx, [var]
```

What values would `[var]` and `ebx` have? And why? When calling `printf` with `%d` I get `2000000000` as a result. But how can this be? `var` can only save 1 byte. How is it possible that a number that requires a larger amount of bytes can be received from it?

Comment: mov [var], eax looks like a 32 bit mov not 8

Comment: For the record, you want `mov [var], al` for a 1-byte store.  And for a narrow load you want `movzx ebx, byte [var]`.  Zeroing EBX ahead of writing the full EBX is pointless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike MASM, NASM doesn’t track the size of variables. (It doesn’t actually have variables, it just has labels.)

So the `mov` instruction from/to a 4-byte register will simply overwrite (or read) whatever is in the four bytes starting at the label `var`.

NASM doesn't stop you from writing buggy code; assembly language doesn't have variables or types; it's up to you to use instructions that make sense for your memory layout.

To do a narrow store:   `mov [var], al`

To do a narrow load (into a full register): `movzx ebx, byte [var]`

Comment: So it would actually overwrite the non-allocated space behind the label when moving more bytes to it than there are allocated?

Comment: the size is determined by the instruction, var is just a label at that point